# vagrant-lamp change src directory

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I started using vagrant-lamp by Matt Andersen (https://github.com/mattandersen/vagrant-lamp)   which maps the the UBUNTU www root directory to /vagrant/src  which maps to a directory on the local machine.    It works fantastic for what I needed it...   It uses, VirtualBox on Windows host with Ubuntu as guest, and provides me with the local development environment I needed.

I am trying to improve it by setting a /vagrant/src1  where src1 is on my Dropbox directory...

I mapped a new share folder in VirtualBox settings, I created a new directory (vagrant/src1) and mounted it in Ubuntu.  Then I changed the vagrant.vhost.conf to point the new directory,  It workes great!

Unfortunately the share folder setting in virtualbox does not stay after a vagrant halt and vagrant up commands.  Something in the vagrant up is overiding my virtuabbox setting after vagrant up command.

Probably something simple, but not sure why -- Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Matt responded to this question on his github and it worked great!
Thank you Matt!

> Assuming that your Dropbox folder is in the regular place and you're
>   on Mac or Linux you need to add the following to the Vagrantfile
>   inside of the Vagrant.configure block:
>
> config.vm.synced_folder "~/Dropbox", "/vagrant/src"
>
> This will mount your Dropbox directory on top of the src directory
>   inside of the Virtual Machine. Apache is configured to look point
>   there for files.